# $\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt \to g(x)$ uniformly when $r\rightarrow \infty$, then $g(x)=ax+b$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose $f$ is a Continuous function on $\Bbb R$ and $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ a function such that $$ \frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt \to g(x) \text{ uniformly }$$ when $r\rightarrow \infty$, then show that $g(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb R$.

I really have no idea on how to approach the problem. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Shouldn't it, by any chance, be the limit when $\;r\to0\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio No, in that case the limit will just be $f(x)$, then there is no question of getting such a specific form!

Comment: @MartinR you can check my other questions, whatever the slightest of idea I have I usually write all of that down. But in this case I really have no idea!

Comment: @Brozovic Well, not $\;f(x)\;$ but rather $\;-f(x)\;$ , but I get your point.

Comment: @Medo $f$ is assumed to be continuous only.

Comment: @Medo: If $f(x) = ax + b$ then the argument of the limit does not blow up.

Comment: @Medo: fine. Anyway, if you take $f(x) = \sin x$ (which is an analytic function), then you get uniform convergence to $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Medo Suppose $f(t)=\cos(t)$.  It's Taylor series has terms of order $x^{2n}$ for all $n\ge 0$.  And yet it has an average value of $0$.  It doesn't "blow up" as you suggested it would.

Comment: @Brozovic, actually the question does not make sense in its current form. See $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt$ is a function of $x$ (and depends only on $x$) whenever the limit exists. How can a function of $x$ converge to another function of $x$. You must talk about a sequence. So either remove the limit $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}$ or drop the $\rightarrow$ sign before $g(x)$, or correct your question in another way!

Comment: @ Rigel. Good. This does not contradict what I said !

Comment: @Mark Viola. I understand. I already said this in my comment to the OP. The OP should write correctly.

Comment: @Medo Please don't just assume that something is wrong with the question, only because you're not familiar with the concept. There are many different definitions of sequences of functions/families of functions converging to a function.

Comment: @Medo The simplest one is [pointwise convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) which means at any point $ x $, the values of the functions in the sequence/family (which form a sequence/ family of numbers) converge to the value of the limit function at that point (which is a single number). The OP has clearly asked for [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence), which is different notion, stronger than pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-a-r}^{x-a +r} f(t)\, dt + \frac{1}{2r}\int_{x+a-r}^{x+a+r} f(t)\, dt \\= \frac{r+a}{r}\frac{1}{2(r+a)}\int_{x - (r+a)}^{ x + (r+a)}f(t) \, dt + \frac{r-a}{r}\frac{1}{{2(r-a)}}\int_{x - (r-a)}^{ x + (r-a)}f(t) \, dt $$

Taking limits with $a$ fixed  we get $g(x- a) + g(x+a) = 2g(x)$ since  $(r \pm a)/r \to 1$ as $r \to \infty$. Substituting with $u = x-a$ and $v = x+a$, it follows that

$$g(u) + g(v) = 2 g ((u+v)/2)$$

Now take $h(x) := g(x) - g(0)$, whence $ h(u) + h(v) = 2h((u+v)/2)$ and $h(0) = 0$.

Thus,

$$h(u+v) = h(u+v) + h(0) = 2h((u+v+0)/2) = 2h((u+v)/2) = h(u) + h(v),$$

and we see that $h$ must be a linear function. It is also continuous as the uniform limit of continuous functions.

Finally, it can be shown that a linear function with points of continuity must be of the form $h(x) = h(1)x$ and, therefore,

$$g(x) = h(x) + g(0) = h(1)x + g(0) = ax+b$$

Comment: Nice proof. So the uniform convergence is not truly necessary in this problem, since any measurable solution of the Cauchy functional equation is of the form $x\mapsto cx$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Thanks for pointing that out.  I suppose also  the pointwise limit of continuous functions must be continuous on a dense set.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post comments, so I'll give some idea in form of an answer. First, note that for $x < y$
$$
g(x) - g(y) = \lim_{r\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{2r} \left( \int_{x-r}^{y-r} f(t)dt + \int_{x+r}^{y+r} f(t)dt\right).
$$
For $y = 0$, we get a new function $h(x) := g(x) - g(0)$. If we can prove that $h$ is linear, we are done. From the above, this seems quite probable, because the integrals on the right should only depend on the gap between $x$ and $y$!

For starting, take $x,y < 0$. Then
$$
\dfrac{1}{2r}\int_{(x+y) - r}^{-r} f(t)dt = \dfrac{1}{2r}\left(\int_{x + y-r}^{y-r} f(t)dt + \int_{y-r}^{-r} f(t)dt\right),
$$
giving
$$
\dfrac{r-y}{r}\dfrac{1}{2(r-y)}\int_{x - (r-y)}^{(r-y)} f(t)dt + \dfrac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{-r} f(t)dt \sim \dfrac{1}{2r} \int_{x-r}^{-r} f(t)dt + \dfrac{1}{2r}\int_{y-r}^{-r}f(t)dt.
$$
You can do the same thing with $x$ and $y$ arbitrary (at first sight...?), also for the second integral. This gives the functional equation
$$
h(x+y) = h(x) + h(y),
$$
which is sufficient for linearity, because we know that $g$ is continuous (uniform convergence).

Comment: Considering that the convergence of $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{2r}\left(\int_{x-r}^{y-r}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_{x+r}^{y+r}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$$ does not necessarily imply the convergence of each of $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{y-r}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{2r}\int_{x+r}^{y+r}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ without any further assumptions, how did you obtain the asymptotic equivalence in the third equation?

Comment: I admit that went a bit fast... To be more precise: if one does the above transformation with both integrals, then sorting the terms, we get the asymptotic for the sum (which we need). So, indeed, one cannot work on the integrals one at a time, but I skipped the transformation for the second, because it should be exactly the same, if I am not mistaken. And for the sum, we get convergence.